# How to get current year?

Tags: datetime, reason, bucklescript

Is there a way to get the current year in Reason? I found a library called [bs-luxon](https://redex.github.io/package/bs-luxon/), but I can't use it. I've installed it as the site says, but I don't know how to import it.

How can I use this library or other way to get the current year?

Comment: `Js.Date` exposes the [Date API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) interface: `Js.Date.now() => 1527009149346`. There also appear to be bindings for moment.js: https://github.com/reasonml-community/bs-moment

Comment: This does makes sense. I though on bs-moment, but in redex it says it's neglected. What does it means?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen How can I convert this in year?

Comment: Look at the Date API documentation I linked, there is a function to get the year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
Js.Date.getFullYear(Js.Date.make())
```

Comment: I got to this same result by trial-and-error based on @HunterMcMillen comment, this is exactly what I wanted!